# On Jenkins, allow users to handle their own credentials but not global ones

Tags: jenkins, credentials

How do you allow users on Jenkins to handle their own credentials (by clicking on their name > Credentials > Global credentials > Add credentials) but I don't want them to access credentials configured globally (by clicking on Credentials from the home page) ?

If I want an user to handle its credentials, I had to set the permission Credentials/View but it also gives access to global credentials.

Comment: What do you mean when you say handle credentials?  As a user should I be able to create an account for myself? Should I choose which permissions I do and do not get?  Or do you simply mean they should be able to change their own password and nothing more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Domain</s> User-specific credentials can be added/modified on **People > username > Configure** or **Credentials**, or by clicking the username on top right and select **Credentials**.

Clicking other users beside the logged in user should not have those shown up when properly restricted (no permissions set for credentials) in Matrix-based authorization configuration.

**Edit:** As it turned out, to be able to see your own credentials, you need to allow the *View* permission on *Credentials* in the Matrix-based permission configuration. Otherwise you can only create credentials, but not view, update or delete them. This is probably not intended and a bug.(Thanks @benjamin.cohen-solal)

Issue reported by @benjamin.cohen-solal [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33872).

Comment: User (and not domain) specific credentials can be added/modified only if I give them the permission Credentials > View,Create,Delete,Update. But with that permission they also can add, view and delete global permissions and I don't want this.

Comment: Sorry, i meant user-specific credentials, i'll edit my post. For me it works to manage the personal credentials of a test user that has no permissions on credentials set in matrix based permissions.

Comment: OK thanks Dominik, so in fact I think there is a bug in my Jenkins version (1.649) because when I remove the permission on credentials to a user, this one cannot see the global credentials. But he can access to his own credentials page. Until there, it's what I wanted. But when he adds a new key, it seems to work (he can choose it as build parameter) but the key doesn't appear on his credentials page. It stays empty. Strange. Thank you for your help Dominik.

Comment: I confirm it's a bug. When I give the "Read" permission on credentials to a user, this one can see all the credentials he previously created, can update and even delete them without I give him the create/update/delete permission

Comment: Now that you say it, i have the same issue. it seems one has to allow the read permission to have credentials to show up in *any* credential provider, even on the own credentials page where you should have full permissions anyways. This is indeed a bug i guess. I will edit this information into the solution, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I created an issue report [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33871)